# Cloud Data Fusion ETL from PostGres to BigQuery - idempotent load

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to use Google's Cloud Data Fusion (CDF) to perform an ETL of some OLTP data in PostGres into BigQuery (BQ). We will copy the contents of a few select tables into an equivalent table in BQ every night - we will add one column with the datestamp.

So imagine we have a table with two columns A & B, and one row of data like this in PostGres

```
|--------------------|
|    A    |    B     |
|--------------------|
|  egg    |  milk    |
|--------------------|
```

Then over two days, the BigQuery table would look like this

```
|-------------------------------|
|    ds    |    A    |    B     |
|-------------------------------|
| 22-01-01 |   egg   |   milk   |
|-------------------------------|
| 22-01-02 |   egg   |   milk   |
|-------------------------------|
```

However, I'm worried that the way I am doing this in CDF is not idempotent and if the pipeline runs twice I'll have duplicate data for a given day in BQ (not desired)

One idea is to delete rows for that day in BQ before doing the ETL (as part of the same pipeline). However, not sure how to do this, or if it is best practice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete the data in a BigQuery action at the start of the pipeline, though that runs into other issues if people are actively querying the table, or if the delete action succeeds but the rest of the pipeline fails.

The BigQuery sink allows you to configure it to upsert data instead of inserting. This should make it idempotent as long as your data has a key that can be used.

Some other possibilities are to place a BigQuery execute after the sink that runs a BigQuery MERGE, or to write a custom Condition plugin that queries BigQuery and only runs the rest of the pipeline if data for the date does not already exist.

Comment: Upsert sounds like an interesting option. I am trying the BQ action to delete the data first... but hitting this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71086487/bigquery-execute-fails-with-no-meaningful-error-on-cloud-data-fusion

Comment: Thanks - went with the upsert functionality on the BQ sink and seems to be working great.

Comment: What do you mean by BigQuery sink? Can you provide documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these 2 options, depending on what you want to do with the information:

**Option 1**

You can create a blank new_table with the same schema (ds,A,B). You will insert the data into the `old_table` from Data Fusion. With the [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_examples) statement, you will compare the data from the `old_table` with the `new_table`; the data that does not exist into the `new_table` will be inserted, and the data that exist and have different data will update this other data.

```
MERGE merge_example.new_table T
USING dataset.old_table S
ON T.ds = S.ds
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET T.A = s.a, T.B=s.b
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT (ds,A, B) VALUES(ds, A, B)
```

**Option 2**

It is the same process as Option 1, but this query only inserts the data that does not exist into the new_table.

```
insert into `dataset.new_table`
select ds, A, B from `dataset.old_table`
where ds not in (select ds from `dataset.new_table`)
```

The difference between Option 1 and Option 2 is that option 1 will update the data that exists which has a different value in the `new_table` and insert the new data. Option 2 will just insert the new data.

You can execute these queries with a Scheduled Query once a day. You can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).