# BigQuery Execute fails with no meaningful error on Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to use the BigQuery Execute function in Cloud Data Fusion (Google). The component validates fine, the SQL checks out but I get this non-meaningful error with every execution:

```
02/11/2022 12:51:25 ERROR Pipeline 'test-bq-execute' failed.
02/11/2022 12:51:25 ERROR Workflow service 'workflow.default.test-bq-execute.DataPipelineWorkflow.<guid>' failed.
02/11/2022 12:51:25 ERROR Program DataPipelineWorkflow execution failed.
```

I can see nothing else to help me debug this. Any ideas? The SQL in question is a simple DELETE from dataset.table WHERE ds = CURRENT_DATE()

[image]

This was the pipeline

```
{
    "name": "test-bq-execute",
    "description": "Data Pipeline Application",
    "artifact": {
        "name": "cdap-data-pipeline",
        "version": "6.5.1",
        "scope": "SYSTEM"
    },
    "config": {
        "resources": {
            "memoryMB": 2048,
            "virtualCores": 1
        },
        "driverResources": {
            "memoryMB": 2048,
            "virtualCores": 1
        },
        "connections": [],
        "comments": [],
        "postActions": [],
        "properties": {},
        "processTimingEnabled": true,
        "stageLoggingEnabled": false,
        "stages": [
            {
                "name": "BigQuery Execute",
                "plugin": {
                    "name": "BigQueryExecute",
                    "type": "action",
                    "label": "BigQuery Execute",
                    "artifact": {
                        "name": "google-cloud",
                        "version": "0.18.1",
                        "scope": "SYSTEM"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "project": "auto-detect",
                        "sql": "DELETE FROM GCPQuickStart.account WHERE ds = CURRENT_DATE()",
                        "dialect": "standard",
                        "mode": "batch",
                        "dataset": "GCPQuickStart",
                        "table": "account",
                        "useCache": "false",
                        "location": "US",
                        "rowAsArguments": "false",
                        "serviceAccountType": "filePath",
                        "serviceFilePath": "auto-detect"
                    }
                },
                "outputSchema": [
                    {
                        "name": "etlSchemaBody",
                        "schema": ""
                    }
                ],
                "id": "BigQuery-Execute",
                "type": "action",
                "label": "BigQuery Execute",
                "icon": "fa-plug"
            }
        ],
        "schedule": "0 1 */1 * *",
        "engine": "spark",
        "numOfRecordsPreview": 100,
        "maxConcurrentRuns": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the pipeline you used in datafusion to replicate your issue?

Comment: Updated to include the pipeline JSON above. It's very simple, just a BQ Execute component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to catch the error using Cloud Logging. To enable Cloud Logging in Cloud Data Fusion, you may use this [GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/viewing-stackdriver-logs#enabling-stackdriver). And follow these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/viewing-stackdriver-logs#viewing_logs) to view the logs from Data Fusion to Cloud Logging. Replicating your scenario this is the error I found:

```
      "logMessage": "Program DataPipelineWorkflow execution failed.\njava.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements\n    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)\n    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)\n    at io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.distributed.AbstractProgramTwillRunnable.run(AbstractProgramTwillRunnable.java:274)\n    at org.apache.twill.interna..."
    }
```

What we did to resolve this error: **Cannot set destination table in jobs with DML statements** is we left the `Dataset Name` and `Table Name` empty inside the pipeline properties as there is no need for the destination table to be specified.

[image]

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]